# Change Windows settings via script

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-10, windows-7-x64, group-policy

I wanted to setup a computer with a variety of settings which I basicly have to do over and over and over again everytime a new user joins our company or changes the computer and I wanted to know if there was a possible way to configure those with a script like I already did with an information colletor script (batch file) and which now works perfectly fine thanks to this webside.

So since I know that here are some really awesome IT Guys with way more experience then me I would love to so something automatic as the next step to save loads of time by simply running a script to configure things like setting up the screensaver, InternetOptions, removing Apps/Softwarelinks in the Start Menu or perhaps even adding links to the bookmark list in firefox or chrome so the user can just start to work and I got loads of time for other important things.

For now it would already be a help to setup a script for Windows 7 but I think we will move more and more to windows 10 so would it be possible to write something to use on both systems without any big changes?

Comment: If your in a AD/Domain environment check out Group Policy which is designed for stuff like this.

Comment: You are asking for a lot be be written for you. How about you open `cmd.exe` and typing help then do `help command` on each so you can see the function of each. It is much easier to setup a policy of some sort and deploying it than doing batch files. but it can be done with batch-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> ... configure things like setting up the screensaver, InternetOptions,
>   removing Apps/Softwarelinks in the Start Menu or perhaps even adding
>   links to the bookmark list in firefox or chrome so the user can just
>   start to work and I got loads of time for other important things.

Everything you ask about can be configured in a centralized fashion via Active Directory Group Policy. Check the [Group Policy Survival Guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4715.group-policy-survival-guide.aspx) page to get started designing the policy for your organization and users.

Group Policy can be defined [using PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx) and via [Group Policy Management Console](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/11/04/windows-server-2012-the-new-and-improved-group-policy-management-console/) which is GUI-based.

Note that the above will only work if you are in Active Directory domain. If you are not, you still can use [**Local** Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725970.aspx), but you will have to run a script on every user's computer. I am not sure whether there are native PowerShell cmdlets to manage Local Group Policy, but AFAIK you can do that via Windows Registry or using special tools.

Comment: ok if this is possible via Group Policy then I think I should try to set something up for some testing because I never really worked with the Group Policy. In school I only saw some basic stuff like creating a new user or giving every user a network drive via login script which I have all forgotten by now but I can find that back from one of my books :P

Thank you for your advice. I will see what I can do with that and how far I get.

Comment: @M.Stephen you are welcome! I'm curious how it will work for you. :)

Comment: I just noticed that I haven't got the time nor the resources to try this so it will have to wait until later :/
But I can try to keep you updated pal :)